# Rendering from to a texture from an FBO causes blurring

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, framebuffer, texture2d

I'm trying to create a Photo editing program using OpenGL ES2 on iOS. I want to be able to modify parts of a photo using the fragment shader. For example, if the user touches the screen that point will be sent to the fragment shader. The fragment shader will add an effect within a certain radius of the point.

What I need is for the modifications made in the fragment shader to be persisted to the next frame. I've read that the way to do this is to setup a second frame buffer object which is associated with a texture. Here's what the program does:

Is the current texture 0? If so this is the first draw so we draw the photo to our FBO (i.e. the texture is projected onto a 2D rectangle). Then re-draw the rectangle to the screen but this time use the FBO as the texture source. After that, we draw the FBO's texture back to the FBO.

i.e.

```
if(_currentTextureID == 0) 
    _currentTextureID = _imageTexture
else 
    _currentTextureID = _frameBufferTextureID;

glBindFrameBuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _frameBufferID)
[self drawTexture: _currentTextureID];

[self bindDrawable]   
[self drawTexture: _currentTextureID];
```

This kind of work but as the draw method is called multiple times the image gets blurry. I thought it might be because you can't render a texture into it's own FBO so I tried with two FBOs but that didn't work either. I'm fairly new to OpenGL so any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Here's a link to the full source:

[Source Code](http://www.deluge.co/?q=content/image-editing-code)

[image: This is an example of the blurring]

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out the problem was in the fragment shader. Previously, the texture coordinate was being represented as a lowp vec2. When I changed it to a highp vec2 the problem disappeared.